# Установка константы в Python файле при сборке whl через setup.py

Tags: python

setup.py берет константу например в env, вызывает setuptools и пакует в WHL. Вот как бы эту константу записать в файл модуля при этом сделать бы это в каталоге build не трогая исходный код.